# git/visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, github, repository, branch

How do I create a new GitHub repository from a local branch from a cloned repo with visual studio?

Been searching and trying for 3 days but nothing works plz help

Answer (score 0):

you can reveal  the files in file explorer from that repository and after that takes the file without git and implement a new git repository

Comment: thank you for your help. But I want to make a repo out a certain commit which I made a branch from and if I do as you said I will get the latest commit in my repo :(        You have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

## In terminal

```
$ cd PARENT-FOLDER

$ git init REPOSITORY-NAME
```

> Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/local/repo/.git/
>
> Creates a new folder on your computer, initialized as a Git repository

$ cd REPOSITORY-NAME

> Changes the working directory

```
$ mkdir docs
```

> Creates a new folder called docs

```
$ cd docs

$ git checkout --orphan newbranch
```

> Creates a new branch, with no history or contents, called newbranch , and switches to the newbranch branch

```
$ git rm -rf .
```

> Removes the contents from your default branch from the working directory

```
git add .
git commit -m ‘’


$ git remote add origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git


$ git push -u origin BRANCH
```

> commits & pushes changes to repo

Comment: Can you tell me how to do with git in visual studio please?

Comment: Open a terminal either Dev CMD or Dev Powershell after cloning the repo and follow the above